# How to show an object sent from flask in HTML?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to display a data model sent from flask app in html. The html only showing
`<rulematrix.visualization.data_model.DataModel object at 0x7f85e55cd050>` not the whole thing.

The object I want to pass is this:
https://github.com/rulematrix/rule-matrix-py/blob/master/rulematrix-demo.gif

I am using the **rule-matrix** library to generate the **datamodel/dashboard**.

https://github.com/rulematrix/rule-matrix-py

Comment: You may have more luck logging an issue against that repo for assistance with this.  Linked from the README there's another (legacy) repo [x-rule](https://github.com/myaooo/x-rule) which has better documentation on the frontend which appears to be written in JS.  There's also a flask backend in the repo, which looks like it serves JSON to that frontend.  In the frame of your question I'm not sure if it's possible to generate the 'object' in that image directly from Python; this looks like a component rendered fully with Javascript, as in the [demo site](http://iml-test2.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. If you have any guidance or further suggestions, please let me know.